# A problem from Real analysis-Royden regarding the finite additivity of bounded disjoint sets for the Lebesgue outer measure

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

Let $A$ and $B$ be bounded sets for which there exists an $\alpha > 0$ s.t $|a-b|\geq \alpha $ $\forall a \in A, b\in B$. Prove that 
$$m^{*}(A\cup B)=m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$$.

Where, $m^{*}$ is the  Lebesgue outer measure.

Now we already have $$m^{*}(A\cup B)\leq m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$$.

But, I couldn't proceed further! Now the author says that the lebesgue outer measure fails to be Countably additive, infact it fails to finitely additive, that is,

there are disjoint set $A$ and $B$ such that
 $$m^{*}(A\cup B)< m^{*}(A)+m^{*}(B)$$.

But the condition in the question precisely says that $A$ and $B$ are disjoint. So, if the question is true, then the boundedness $A$ and $B$ is essential.
Am I true in this regard? How do I solve the problem?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: from inequality it seems like $A$ and $B$ havent' common elements. so they are disjoint.

Comment: Yes correct .. that is what I have already wriiten in the last paragraph of the post.

Answer (score 0):

*Hints:* The point is that $A$ and $B$ are not only disjoint but they are well separated; so they can be covered by balls (or cubes or whatever you use to generate the Lebesgue outer measure in your favorite definition) independently. Draw a picture. That should help a lot.